# どうして.containerで15pxして.rowで-15pxするのでしょうか？

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

基本的に`Bootstrap`は`.container`で括ってその中で`.row`を記述していく書き方をします。
なのに何故、わざわざ`Bootstrap`は`.container`で`15px`して`.row`で`-15px`しているのでしょうか？

該当ソースリンク：
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css#L22
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css#L62

Answer (score 4):

`.container`の中に`.row`しか書かないのであれば、`.container`で`15px`して`.row`で`-15px`するのは無駄ですよね。

しかし、`.container`は名前のとおり入れ物なので`.row`以外のものを入れることも多いです。例えば、下のような例を考えると、`.container`で`15px`して`.row`で`-15px`していることによって、「タイトル」と「文章」とグリッド内の表示が自然に揃います。要するに開発者が使いやすくするためでしょう。

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>タイトル</h2>
  <p>文章<p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

row の中で マイナスマージンを使うのは  その中に プラスマージンの 要素を入れることが
目的だからではないでしょうか？

float で 複数の BOX を row の 中に入れると思いますが、自動的にきれいに折り返して
表示するための工夫だったような・・。

探してみたら [その部分を 解説しているサイトがありました。](https://www.m-hand.co.jp/coding/1285/)
「マイナスの値も指定可能！」の部分。

Bootstrap を使えば このような CSS の細かなトリックを知らずに
きれいなレイアウトができるので人気なんだと思います。